# PHP function to list files from path

Tags: php, function

I have a variable which contains a path to folder ($path_to_folder)
Looking how to build a function who will return all the files in this folder as a comma separated list.. 
I have tried

```
$files = dirList($path_to_folder);
sort($files);
```

but I could not use this as my function

Thanks...

Comment: If you want a comma separated list, then just `implode()` $files with a comma separator

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to turn it into a comma separated list you could do the following:

```
$files = implode( ',', scandir( $directory ) );
```

Of course you will probably want to make sure that the scandir() gets an actual result so you'll want to bring that out to the following:

```
$files = scandir( $directory );

if( $files )
{
    $files = implode( ',', $files );
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php